# Ionic-native-file can't read file first time after save file

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework

I can't read file first time after saving file.
-But when i restart the app i can read file.
-And I set "Application supports iTunes file sharing", i can read file first time.

//File save

```
 this.file.writeFile(filedir,'sample.txt','hellow owlrd')
        .then((data)=>{
            this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
        }).catch(err=>
        {
            alert('ff'+JSON.stringify(err));
        });
```

//File Read

```
       var filedir = this.file.documentsDirectory ;
  this.file.listDir(filedir,'recordtext').then((files)=>
  {      
       var i =0 ;

       for( let myfile of files){

         this.file.readAsText(filedir,myfile.fullPath.substr(1)).then((contents)=>{

             this.pushArray.push(this.getSubStr(contents));
             this.txtNames.push(myfile.fullPath.substr(1));                      
         })
       }            
  });
```

It seems that close file not work well.
I don't know the reason correctly.
Please help.

Comment: Probably because you are using `writeFile` for both, saving and reading?

Comment: It's not.
I have 2 pages: one is save page and the other is write page.

Comment: When saving file is success, viewctrl is dismissed.
sorry, I resubmitted the read code.

Comment: Then please update your question so it does not suggest so. You added comments `//File save` and `//File read` and below both of them you use `writeFile`.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using a `catch` for the file read operation? If it's not working, it should probably return an error of some sort, which would help solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the index.html
I moved

before

```
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

And the problem is solved.